# Driving Eligibility with a Valid Foreign License & Learner's Permit Newyork DMV

Tags: driving

https://nysdmv.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/406/~/drive-with-a-valid-foreign-driver-license-and-a-new-york-state-learner-permit

Based on the information in the page, Can anyone please confirm whether you can use a valid foreign license with a New York Learner's Permit to drive in the Newyork State ? Will these documents be sufficient Incase I get pulled over ?

The answer in page points to that a foreign license allows me to drive the vehicle. Foreign (or out-of-state) licenses are not valid once a person becomes a resident of New York State. Does this invalidate my eligibility if I am a resident of the new york state ?

Comment: The first word in the answer on the page you linked to is "yes."  Why don't you trust that?  What additional information do you hope to get by asking here?

Comment: Thanks for your question phoog, I have updated the question with more information. The gist of my question is to understand whether my foreign license is not valid anymore If I become a resident of the newyork state.

Comment: State law does not affect the validity of a foreign license outside the state; however, surrendering the license might.

Comment: Can you please point to an official web page describing this ?